# What is the most efficient way to store n-grams in a database / data structure?

Tags: computational-linguistics, n-grams

Let's assume we have Google's 1T n-grams. I want to be able to:

- Search for n-grams containing all of a set of words (such as finding all n-grams containing the words "dog" and "bone" in any position)
- The above search but for n-grams of a particular size only
- Search for n-grams using a template (such as finding all n-grams which fit the template "the dog __ the __" where the blanks are to be filled with a single word)

Comment: Welcome! I think you might get better answers at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), the Stack Exchange devoted to programming. (I tried to choose this for my close vote, but only Meta Linguistics was offered as a choice...).

Comment: Actually I think that this is more closely related to natural language processing than to programming itself. This is the closest stack exchange to NLP.

Comment: @mtanti: I don't see anything here about natural language processing. This is just about data, so computational linguistics but not NLP.

Answer (score 1):

The [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure is commonly used in NLP. This, and its descendants, [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) and [Generalized Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) provide both, an efficient way to store commonly occurring sub-sequences, and a fast way to search for sub-sequences.

Comment: I agree but can a trie be efficiently represented in a database?

Comment: It can but a nosql database might be more suitable for the representation than a relational database.

Comment: @mtanti: I don't have any experience with databases. Aren't database keys hashes? If so, it can't be efficiently represented. However, if you were creating your own database, you can use this Trie itself as a hash. That should make searches very fast.

Comment: They're more likely to be b-trees which are basically sorted trees. I'm programming in Python and I don't think there's an easy way to make generic file based data structures.

Answer (score 1):

You could store all tokens in a relational database in a separate table and build up a positional index (sacrificing space for speed of query processing). Then you could use simple SQL expressions to formulate all types of queries you've listed.

Comment: Actually the WHERE statement "WHERE (ele0 = 'dog' or ele1 = 'dog' or ele2 = 'dog' or ele3 = 'dog') AND (ele0 = 'bone' or ele1 = 'bone' or ele2 = 'bone' or ele3 = 'bone')" is quite slow.

Comment: It shouldn't be if you use a good index but what I meant is having an explicit index on a table with the tokens and their positions in the tuple.

Comment: It is indexed but still too slow to process in bulk operations. In my case I want to check which words tend to replace a word in an ngram for every word in the corpus.

Comment: In this case sql won't work. Build up an efficient structure in memory and use an efficient (procedural) language to execute queries.

Comment: I would but there's too much data to keep it in memory.